# Python function does not return expected result but its name and address

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am learning python and I have a problem with a supposedly simple function, can anyone tell me why my function is not working?

```
def sum_numbers (num1, num2):
    return  num1 + num2
sum_numbers(10, 20)
print(sum_numbers)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and format the code correctly. Also, what do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: You are trying to print the function, not the result of the function call

Answer (score 1):

Printing the name of the function probably results in something like this:

`<function sum_numbers at 0x7fa7483162f0>`

To print the sum of the numbers, you may either assign the result of the function to a variable and print the variable or print the function with the parameters:

```
def sum_numbers (num1, num2):
    return  num1 + num2


print(sum_numbers)
print(sum_numbers(10, 20))
result = sum_numbers(3, 5)
print(result)
```